# How to convert es6 destructuring and rename argument to typescript?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to convert my es6 code to typescript. In this case, I need to split the argument into 2 parts. Could anyone provide the typescript version, please?

```
const es6 = ({a:A, ...B}) => {
    console.log(A, B);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is already valid Typescript.

However, if you want to add types, just place them to the right.

For example:

```
interface MyType {
    a: number;
    [key: string]: any;
}

const es6 = ({ a: A, ...B }: MyType) => {
    console.log(A, B);
}
```

Here `B`'s type will be inferred to `{ [key: string]: any }`.

Comment: thanks, I still have 2 problems : 

1: I don't know what is another property in the argument, except "a";

2: I need the argument property "a" rename as "A";

Comment: @Kenny Cheung, I udpated my answer